# My app keeps on crashing after recompilation and signing

Tags: javascript, android, reverse-engineering, digital-signature

i got a android app i decompiled it , i made some changes , recompiled signed with the test key and keeps on crashing within 3 secs of launch , after that i just decompilied and recompiled again without any changes and after signing with the test key it crashes again so you got any suggestions ? i don't have the original key ofc so that not the fix even trying to get the signature out from the original untouched app doesn't work it just says the app is unsigned i tried using apksigcopier for the job , tried using logcat to find where the app crashes these part only constains the error meassage so if you know what i am doing and can help me surely welcome

```
E  Access denied finding property "vzw.os.rooted"
E  type=1327 audit(1710166837.547:15782): proctitle="com.app.name"
 A  FORTIFY: pthread_mutex_lock called on a destroyed mutex (0x7bd9076298)
A  Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 24555 (Thread-13), pid 11341 (com.app.name)
A  FORTIFY: pthread_mutex_lock called on a destroyed mutex (0x7bd90bf1c0)
 A  FORTIFY: pthread_mutex_lock called on a destroyed mutex (0x7c7ba31a88)
A  FORTIFY: pthread_mutex_lock called on a destroyed mutex (0x7c7ba31a88)
```

these lines of the code are only in red